# limit logs amount for docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

i have a rails project which i start with

```
docker-compose up
```

however each time i start it, docker-compose outputs logs for all previous containers, and its increasingly more and more...

how do i limit the output of logging on startup?

here's my docker-compose.yml, it it helps...

```
web:
  build: .
  command: bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'
  environment:
    RAILS_ENV: development
  volumes:
    - .:/rcd
  ports:
    - "3000:3000"
  external_links:
    - postgres:db
  volumes_from:
    - bundle
bundle:
  image: rcd_web
  command: echo "hi"
  volumes:
    - /bundle
```

and here's Dockerfile:

```
FROM ruby:2.1
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential libpq-dev nodejs
ENV APP_HOME /rcd
RUN mkdir $APP_HOME
WORKDIR $APP_HOME
ADD Gemfile* $APP_HOME/
ENV BUNDLE_GEMFILE=$APP_HOME/Gemfile \
BUNDLE_JOBS=2 \
BUNDLE_PATH=/bundle
RUN bundle install --without production development test
ADD . $APP_HOME
ENV PATH ~/bin:$PATH
```

i can of course remove all old containers with:

```
 docker rm `docker ps -aq`
```

but i dont want to do it on each startup..

here's f.ex. logging after three stop/start

```
~/workspace/rcd$ docker-compose up
Starting rcd_bundle_1...
Starting rcd_web_1...
Attaching to rcd_bundle_1, rcd_web_1
bundle_1 | hi
bundle_1 | hi
bundle_1 | hi
web_1    | => Booting WEBrick
web_1    | => Rails 4.2.4 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
web_1    | => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
web_1    | => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
web_1    | Exiting
web_1    | [2015-11-17 11:52:16] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
web_1    | [2015-11-17 11:52:16] INFO  ruby 2.1.7 (2015-08-18) [x86_64-linux]
web_1    | [2015-11-17 11:52:16] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=1 port=3000
web_1    | [2015-11-17 11:52:16] FATAL SignalException: SIGTERM
web_1    |  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:170:in `select'
web_1    |  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:170:in `block in start'
web_1    |  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:32:in `start'
web_1    |  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:160:in `start'
web_1    |  /bundle/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:34:in `run'
web_1    |  /bundle/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:286:in `start'
web_1    |  /bundle/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:80:in `start'
web_1    |  /bundle/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in `block in server'
web_1    |  /bundle/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
web_1    |  /bundle/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
web_1    |  /bundle/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
web_1    |  /bundle/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
web_1    |  bin/rails:8:in `require'
web_1    |  bin/rails:8:in `<main>'
web_1    | [2015-11-17 11:52:16] INFO  going to shutdown ...
web_1    | [2015-11-17 11:52:16] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start done.
web_1    | => Booting WEBrick
web_1    | => Rails 4.2.4 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
web_1    | => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
web_1    | => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
web_1    | Exiting
web_1    | [2015-11-17 11:52:22] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
web_1    | [2015-11-17 11:52:22] INFO  ruby 2.1.7 (2015-08-18) [x86_64-linux]
web_1    | [2015-11-17 11:52:22] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=1 port=3000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this issue was fixed in docker-compose 1.5. You'll only get logs from the time to start the container.

Comment: Confirmed !
That is great news, I had the same "issue" for weeks... :/